# How to get a navigationbar logo and Name in the same space as the nav-links?

Tags: html, css

I am teaching myself how to design a website and i stumbled upon a problem.

I tried a couple of things but the problem remains. The nav-brand is included in the same box as the nav but not inside the same as the nav-links.

I want the nav-brand Logo and Text on the left side and same height as the nav-links.

HMTL

```
<nav>
    <div class="nav-brand">
      <a>BIKE</a>
    </div>
    <div class="hamburger">
      <div class="line"></div>
      <div class="line"></div>
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>   
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

CSS

```
nav {
  height: 10vh;
  background: transparent;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.nav-links li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.nav-brand {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also add display flex at the nav element.

```
nav {
  height: 10vh;
  background: transparent;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.nav-links li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.nav-brand {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
nav {
  height: 10vh;
  background: transparent;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  width: 50%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.nav-links li a {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.nav-brand {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class="nav-brand">
      <a>BIKE</a>
    </div>
    <div class="hamburger">
      <div class="line"></div>
      <div class="line"></div>
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>   
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: there are nothing much only height and float property use